# How does the JS engine collaborate with WebCore to update the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit

[image]

I curious about rendering engine (webkit) work internally... And so i get this image above

So mt problem and question is

I confused about web api, that is produced by JS engine and then JS engine will be interpreter that and will be communicate into webcore for updating DOM tree?? Its correct??

I guess DOM tree and render object is located at rendering engine (webcore) and to do manipulate that DOM tree rendering engine provide a api and JS engine also provide api in their languange

Is that my guess is correct??

Thankss